# Dojo HorizontalLinearGauge after dijit .startup()

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am attempting to create a Dojo layout using this code:

```
require([ 'dijit/registry', 'dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 'dijit/layout/TabContainer', 'dijit/layout/ContentPane', 'dojo/store/Memory', 'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync', 'gridx/Grid', 'dojox/dgauges/components/default/HorizontalLinearGauge', 'dojox/charting/Chart', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function(
  registry,
  BorderContainer,
  TabContainer,
  ContentPane,
  Memory,
  Sync,
  Grid,
  HorizontalLinearGauge,
  Chart
) {
Layout = new BorderContainer({
  'design' : 'headline',
  'class': 'borderContainerLayout'
}, 'dashboardLayout');
Layout.addChild(new ContentPane({
  'id': 'layoutRight',
  'region' : 'right',
  'content': '<div id="days-between-purchases"></div>',
  'splitter': true
}));
Layout.startup();
var hlg = new HorizontalLinearGauge({
  'title': 'Purchase Cycle (Average # of days between purchases)',
  'srcRefNode': 'abc',
  'value': 20,
  'class': 'gauge',
  'noChange': true,
  'width': 150,
  'height': 150,
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100,
}, registry.byId('days-between-purchases'));
hlg.render();
```

There is more code to add a center, left, etc to the BorderContainer, but the problem I'm getting is "Unable to get property 'nodeType' of undefined or null reference.  From the DOM captured at the time, it seems that the layout is not yet rendered into the DOM, so it cannot find registry.byId('days-between-purchases').  I have tried about 10 different ways of trying to put this together to render the layout and gauge during run time and searched heavily for a solution, but have come up with nothing.

What am I doing wrong?  Do you know of a tutorial which shows how to fully render a layout with a gauge at runtime?  Sample code?

Thanks, in advance.

FYI: I am using the latest version of dojo with this dojoConfig:

```
var dojoConfig = {
baseUrl : "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/",
async : true,
isDebug : true,
parseOnLoad : false,
//gfxRenderer: "svg,silverlight,vml",

packages : [ {
  name : "dojo",
  location : "dojo"
}, {
  name : "dijit",
  location : "dijit"
}, {
  name : "dojox",
  location : "dojox"
}, {
  'name': 'gridx',
  'location': '/resources/common/javascript/gridx'
}]
```

};

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution.  It was two-fold:

1) Instead of using registry.byId, I needed to use dom.byId
2) Christophe was correct in the statement that render() is not a method; I had to use startup()

Now, I have no idea how to use fiddle, but I tried to create one that has all the code so that people in the future can see what I pieced together. http://jsfiddle.net/hUN9Y/

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand what is going on as your sample does not seem to be fully runnable? In particular I don't think gauges have a render() method and you are calling render on it?

In dojox/dgauges/tests/test_all.html you will find a test showing gauges used in a BorderContainer. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I'm checking now, but I have a noob question, if you don't mind... When posting, is it best to include fully runnable code?  I truncated it so that it would only have the apparently-pertinent sections of code.  Thanks!

Comment: Ideally should be able to extract a runnable piece of code that is still reasonable size to be posted. If you can't extract a reasonably sized piece of code, then obviously you don't have much choice than just posting an excerpt as you did. But then it might be more difficult to figure out the issue.